# Reference is not getting displayed

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I have kept my references in a `refer.bib` file. My file looks like following:

```
@ARTICLE{seya12,
author={Y. Seya and S. Mori},
journal={Atten Percept Psychophys (2012) }, 
title={Spatial attention and reaction times during smooth pursuit eye movement},
year={2012},
number={74},
pages={493-509},
doi={10.3758/s13414-011-0247-y},


@ARTICLE{chen02,
author={Y. Chen and P.S. Halzman},
journal={Progress in Brain Research (2002) }, 
title={Visual and cognitive control of attention in smooth pursuit.},
year={2002},
number={140},
pages={255-265},
```

**Problem:** My first reference `[seya2012]` is getting appeared when i cite it but the second reference (i.e. `\cite{chen02}`) , it doesn't appear. I am getting `[?]` at its place.

**My process:** I press `F6` then `F11` then again `F6` and `F6` and then finally i run it.

**PS:** I am writing paper in `IEEEtran`

Comment: I'm afraid you're not providing much information; please consider adding an MWE (minimum working example program) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has no closing `}`s

```
@ARTICLE{seya12,
author={Y. Seya and S. Mori},
journal={Atten Percept Psychophys (2012) }, title={Spatial attention and reaction times during smooth pursuit eye movement},
year={2012},
number={74},
pages={493-509},
doi={10.3758/s13414-011-0247-y},
}%added


@ARTICLE{chen02,
author={Y. Chen and P.S. Halzman},
journal={Progress in Brain Research (2002) }, title={Visual and cognitive control of attention in smooth pursuit.},
year={2002},
number={140},
pages={255-265},
}%added
```

btw. pressing buttons doesn't explain us, which programs run